# RotateFunction has different behaviours

Tags: c#, rotation, unity-game-engine

I wrote function of class Card, which should rotate Card in time around its Y-axis.

```
public IEnumerator RotateCard(float angle)
{
     if(rotating)
         yield break;
     rotating = true;
     float newAngle = curRotation.y + angle;
     while(curRotation.y < newAngle)
     {   
         curRotation.y = Mathf.MoveTowards(curRotation.y, newAngle, rotateSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
         transform.eulerAngles = curRotation;
         yield return null;
      }
      rotating = false;
}
```

And I have to calls of this function in Card.OnMouseDown():

```
IEnumerator OnMouseDown()
{
     print ("Card clicked");
     yield return StartCoroutine( RotateCard(180));
     yield return StartCoroutine(gameManager.actionDeck[0].RotateCard(180));
}
```

where gameManager is object that contains list of Cards actionDeck.

First call does what function is meant to do - rotates Card around its Y-axis.
Second call on the other hand rotates Card around some strange point.

Any ideas why and how to make it work in the same manner as with call #1?

Comment: `yield return null;` ... why?

Comment: Most likely it's rotating around a parent object. Maybe try `gameManager.actionDeck[0].gameObject.RotateCard(180)` or something like that?

Comment: Calling through gameObject didnt work - it doesnt have access to RotateCard() function.     yield return null; ... why? - function has to return something. This way it started working so i didnt ask more questions... –

Comment: Without seeing your object hierarchy or more of your implementation it's hard to provide an answer.  As written, the code is fine and in my test case both objects rotate around their local y-axis.

Comment: @LightStriker He is writing a coroutine which expects a Yield instruction

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use transform.localEulerAngles instead?